# Creating nested Linear layout dynamically with weights to have multiple buttons on same line

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a toggle button that will display more buttons and some `TextView` like shown below.

[image]

With the toggle button ON it will display the `TextView`s and 3 extra buttons, once switched off it will close those, Rearranging the toggle buttons below it as shown.

The part I specifically need help with is creating the second linear layout and setting weightings for each of my buttons?

```
Public void toggleswtich(){
                layout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.ReportsLayout);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100);
                lp.weight = 1;
                Button enterJob = new Button(Reports.this);
                layout.setLayoutParams();
               // if (button.isActivated()) {
                    enterJob.setText("Open");
                    layout.setWeightSum(1);
                    layout.addView(enterJob);


                    enterJob.setOnClickListener(OnClickOpenComp(enterJob));
               // }
               // else {
                    enterJob.setText("Clsoe");
                    layout.addView(enterJob);

                    enterJob.setOnClickListener(OnClickOpenComp(enterJob));
                      //}
                 }
```

As requested this is my xml, however there isnt much to show as everything is created with code in run time once a Job is saved.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ReportsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/bEmptyJN"
        android:text="Enter Job number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<requestFocus
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here's what it looks like with jobs, picture the jobs as toggle buttons

[image: What I've accomplished]

Let me know if you'd like anymore information

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the result? Can you also post your XML?

Comment: Are you having difficulty with making the buttons appear or with their weighting?

Comment: With the weighting, i cant seem to divide the linear layout into 3 so it displays the 3 buttons next to each other. So far I'm only able to generate them below each other.